# How to make cloth simulation not to fall inside the floor?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

So I made a cloth simulation, it should fall on the floor, but it falls inside of it. I set the floor as Rigid Body Passive, but it`s still not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor will need a Collision modifier applied.

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!!